# changing the properties (details) of a file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file, properties

How can I change the properties (details) of a file in Matlab?
by details I mean things like "album", "track#", "artist", etc. (for an audio file).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties that you mention are not general file properties, but specific properties supported by specific file formats. For MP3 files for instance, that information is normally stored using an extension called [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3). To modify the information, you either need to use a library for that purpose or implement it yourself. According to [id3.org](http://id3.org/Implementations) there is no Matlab implementation. However, it might be possible to get the Java implementation working using Matlab's built-in Java support.

Comment: I can use Java or PHP. Thanks very much for your good answer.